# Nginx ReWrite Engine - Transform Apache Rules to Nginx

Tags: model-view-controller, nginx, http-headers, url-rewriting

I need to transform those Apache rules to Nginx for my MVC.

Apache Rules :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/system/maintenance.html -f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !maintenance.html
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/system/maintenance.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RwriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I think that some of it i can handle for the first part for the maintenance i think that this can help:

```
location / {
root       /var/www/myapp.com/current/public;

try_files /system/maintenance.html
          $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html
          @app-server_cluster;
```

}

but the second block of the QSA,L i don't know.

Thanks for your Help!

Comment: Implementing the `index.php` rule is somewhat dependent on the contents of your `@app-server_cluster` block.

Comment: can you explain why ? it seems not to work properlly

Comment: You will need to expand your question first. I cannot deduce what your `@app-server_cluster` block is trying to do. We need to see more of your configuration.

Comment: please help me with this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44346456/apache-auth-rules-converted-for-nginx-server