# Apache auth rules converted for nginx server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx

Please help me to convert these .httacces rules from apache to nginx rules

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
```

Thank you.